# How to handle when in the predicted data there are attribute values that are not available in the model of decision tree

Tags: classification, data-mining, decision-tree

I have several attributes, one of which is JOB. in the decision tree model that I formed, JOB has 6 values in it namely "doctor", "civil servant", "farmer", "teacher", "police", "accountant". then, I want to predict data with the JOB attribute with the value "fisherman". how can i solve this problem? Because in the tree that I formed, there are no attributes with that value.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying the decision tree model was fit on data without any fisherman values?

Comment: @dkhara yes, that's what I mean

Comment: You need to fit your model on data with fisherman values. Without information about fishermen, your model can't predict anything about them. It sounds like you have too little data. If you can, try using on-hand data or collecting additional data with fisherman values. Otherwise, your model can't make this prediction.

Comment: @dkhara but in the future, there will be a lot of new jobs that don't fit with my model, so I really can't predict that kind of data, right?

Comment: Correct, you can't predict that kind of data. Your model is only as good as the data it is fed. Typically, if you want to build a robust model, you need a lot of data, which can be the most challenging part of the process sometimes.

Comment: @dkhara oh i see, okay, thanks for answering